# I need to redirection for my url using cloudfront and s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a url say `example.com/eu/blog/` , in this page ,I have a button , when any user click on button , it goes to `oil-gas.com/en` (this is a different website) .. now I want this link to be as `example.com/eu/blog/oil-gas/en` and currently I don't have anything in `example.com/eu/blog/oil-gas/en` .

I have used apache proxypass and it works , but I want to know if we can do this using S3 , cloudfront .. can we create bucket in S3 and enable static hosting with redirection ... I want the url to be specifically `example.com/eu/blog/oil-gas/en`. Please help or advice more

Answer (score 0):

You can set a redirect in CloudFront by adding a [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) function. This would be added to the Origin Response event.

The code would look like the below

```
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
 
     request = event["Records"][0]["cf"]["request"]
     response = event["Records"][0]["cf"]["response"]
     
     #If it matches this path perform a redirect
     if request['uri'] == "url/to/redirect":
    
         response = {
             'status': '302',
             'statusDescription': 'Found',
             'headers': {
                 'location': [{
                     'key': 'Location',
                     'value': 'http://example.com/eu/blog/oil-gas/en'
                 }]
             }
         }
     
     return response
```

Here are some [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html).